# 'Required' fields on Drupal User Registration profiles not required when using Bootstrap Login Modal

Tags: profile, drupal-7

We're using the Bootstrap Login Modal module to display the Drupal user login/registration forms as popups, rather than a separate page. I've just realised that while the module is enabled it's possible to submit the form without completing the fields from the CiviCRM user registration profiles that are marked as required. This seems to be the case even if I submit the form directly from https://example.net/user/register without displaying it as a modal. As soon as I disable the module, leaving the fields blank generates an error on form submission as expected.

Does anyone know of a fix or workaround?

CiviCRM 5.70.1 and Drupal 7.99